# Cannot push to remote from bare repo in git?

Tags: git

I have a problem in which I can connect to the my team's central repo from a intermediate server. So I created a bare clone of the repo on that server and I push my changes to that bare repo. Then I log into the server and push to the central repo from there. 
Today I pushed some code into the bare repo while someone had pushed changes into the central repo. Now when I tried to push I was getting non-fast forward errors. 
Now if I fetch into the bare repo and try to pull from it to my working repo I am getting that it is already uptodate. How do I fix this issue?

On a side note is there a better workflow for this scenario?

Comment: Please elaborate more, based on assumptions you need to pull from central repo to bare repository. Maybe thing about a new branch and merge there and push to a new branch in central repository